# Compositing fog destroys PNG alpha in Images as Planes when using Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, image, transparency

I'm following Andrew Price's spaceship tutorial and taking advantage of the inbuilt addon called *Import Images as Planes*.

[image]

Here you can see 2 Images as Planes used for the steam columns, close to the door.
If you ask **why?**, it's because I already have enough polygons, for my laptop to render...
And I thought that a `smoke simulation` would simply be an **overkill**.

**Issue**:

I wanted to try compositing, even if I'm still not ready with the definitive 
geometries and textures.
And... All is fine except for **mist**.

You can see I can use some `Blur` and `Glare` withuot big issues (apart the orange LED 
wall panels which became white - so I thought to assign them a different `Material 
Pass` and a separate `ID Mask` - now they are pinkish, but not so bad at all).

[image]

But! If I enable the `Map Value` node, which creates the mist... what happens it 
that the steam columns contours are MANGLED (well, not only the contours)!!

[image]

Now, is there a way to **fix** this issue (is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?) or do I have to give up and sacrifice that wornderful **oniric** mist?

**[EDIT]**

To whom can be interested in: the original blend is [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ezs3ac34a26aa3f5ce6650303da779cb7c9b/BlenderGuru_SpaceshipCorridor_Part1.blend) (much better han mine).

Here's the Steam column I used for both `Images as Planes`:

[image]

You can't see it because it's **white** on a transparent background, resulting in white on white.

Comment: If i understand your setup, your problem is not alpha but MatID mask with AA. try to change your final add node(s) for mix node(s).

Comment: I'll try, thank you. Allow me 1 hour to try.

Comment: Could you [post a .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? It would make it much easier to test, thanks :D

Comment: @Bithur Unfortunately, it didn't work :(

Comment: That's too bad, could you upload your file like GCF suggested? You can simplify it and remove non applicable things you don't want to share, just make sure the issue is present in the file you send.

Comment: I posted a link to the original file AND the steam PNG I'm using. Better, because the quality of Andrew Price's meshes is really on a different planet!

Comment: Ok, having your specific blend might be necessary though, as I might not be able to replicate the issue.

Comment: I cannot post a binary file other than an image... can I?

Comment: Go [**here**](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and upload your .blend, and copy the link into your question. That should do the trick

Comment: OK, thank you. Now please give me about an hour. Since I'm also doing some other things in the moment being.

Comment: No problem, I'll try using the default file for now.

Comment: I uploaded a file which is a modified version of the original. Now the problem seems to be slightly different (you don't see the ugly Alpha, but a transparency box around the stream). But always connected to the PNG transparency

Answer (score 4):

The problem is Z Channel in Cycles - it does not take into account material transparency:

[image]

I recommend not using the Z channel pass but to render nice custom Z pass like this:

Assign this material to scene objects (this material has value based of ray length - distance to camera):

[image]

[image]

You will get nice anti-aliased Z-depth render that you can use for the mist.  For alpha-transparent planes mix in Transparent shader like in the image and **render them on separate render layer** so there's nothing behind them (then composite them back in).

To create [group node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Node_Groups) group them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. Go inside and outside group node with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Is `Z_Depht` a **standard node** in Blender? And `Group Input`? I guess I never noticed them, before. As I said, it's only 4 months I started with Blender.

Comment: The Z_Depth node is a group (user made), the second image shows what's inside. The Group inputs are the inputs you see for the Z_Depth node in the 1st image.

Comment: Let me try to recreate this structure.

Comment: OK, done, trying to render an Image-Plane with this new material... `Emission` instead of `Diffuse`? How funny! But maybe it's due to Cycles youth?

Comment: @DerGolem Well you don't need any lights for this material - the front will be shadeless white (emission) and the back will be black(no material there). You can also input the shaders the other way round for inverted result. Then you just play with farpoint and contrast to adjust the mapping.

Comment: Well... unfortunately it's even **worse** (not that it was beautiful, before). Now I end up with an **inverted Alpha** (where it should be transparent is greyish and where it should be white is transparent).

Comment: @DerGolem The custom z-pass for the fog went well? Is the issue in the compositing nodes? I can't look into your .blend now but later will inspect it.

Comment: No. Now it's giving a bad looking material during rendering also.

Comment: Now I `swapped Z-Depth and Transparent`. And it **renders** well! Waiting for it to finish to see if compositing ruins it again.

Comment: @DerGolem What about moving the smoke to separate render layer and then just alpha over it in post-pro? That should be the easiest option.

Comment: Sounds interesting... but now I need to follow a tutorial on overlaying layers in post production. Just wait about 10 minutes, I did a render but I forgot to assign the new material to ALL the steam columns. I did just 1 and it was PERFECT (but I don't know if the mist arrives to touch it) - doing it again. And crossing my fingers.

Comment: No... Only the closest to the observer was rendered well (greyish). The other ones are blackish. And pixellated, too. I think I'll give up.

Comment: @DerGolem If you adjust the Farpoint and Contrast of the Z-Depth group node you will get better range - I believe the objects are black because they are clipped black - it works similar as MapRange compositing node for zdepth pass.

Comment: Errr... hmmm... OK, I gave up. Maybe I can add the myst like the steam, by using another `Image as Plane`. And renounce to the composited fog.