# Editing with 3 layers but 1 should be the foreground of the background

Tags: edit-mode, transparency

So I'm trying to find a solution for my new video editing project.
In layer 1 (so the background) should be my original video which contains a background of a greenscreen alike texture.
I figured out to get that out of the screen with composting and the most of it is transparent whereas the person in front is still visible (which should be layer 3).
That is because there should be a second layer (layer 2) in the middle with some effects (only 2D effects like a PNG file - so pretty easy). So the person is still visible and the effects and if them are disabled you see the normal background.

So first question:
Can I do that in 1 blender file? And if I can - how can I?
If not: should I render the file of the composting blender file first and than put it on layer 3? And if so, should I render it as png or is there another way as a video file so I can just export that? And since it's not so easy to render in composting mode - how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Probably related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160706/2214

Comment: Thank you! We'll that helps, yes, but it could be a bit to "big". My "effects" should stay in 2D. So there is just another layer (e.g. A PNG file) for that to be added in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I used two *Scenes* ... one used to *Composite > Matte* greenscreen (because *VSE* has no matte tools). Second scene for *VSE* to mix channels (because you cant add strip Scene of current scene).

Footage
[image]

Scene named "Scene Matte"
[image]

Scene named "Scene VSE"
[image]

Layer 1 original *Footage*, Layer 2 effect (Text Strip in this sample), Layer 3 Scene strip named "Scene Matte" with matted Footage.

[image]

Comment: Looks good and looks like this could really help me. Thank you! Gonna try this as fast as i get to that!