# (How) Can I get rid of these fireflies in the zDepth pass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/twSI1.jpg

How do i fix the firefly type artifacts? None of the leaves have a glossy surface so that shouldn't be causing the problem?

Here's a file of just the front tree. (sorry for the file size)
Updated version.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5m46lz9vzqehhh7/Toussaint%20-%20Copy.blend?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Shaders shouldn't affect the Z-pass. It looks to me that what you are facing is some kind of Z precision error. Try limiting the near and far clipping distances for the camera, so that the clipping starts at the closest object and ends at the farthest one.

Comment: I don't think they are fireflies. Those same spots are in the color render too. Maybe reflections or highlights... Nice job BTW

Comment: Does the second picture contain some post-processing with the faulty z-buffer? The leaves look weird where there is an error in the z-buffer. If not, try fixing this on your model.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a blend with just the foreground bush to let us see the error up close? That would be helpful. Also a screenshot of your comp nodes would be good too.

Comment: @elmo274 It would be helpful if you posted a file that contains the tree that is close to the camera **and** the object that is the farthest away. Otherwise is hard to determine precision issues.

Comment: @cegaton i updated the file for you

Comment: No issues here... http://i.stack.imgur.com/de37R.png

Comment: @cegaton That's because there is not leaf texture for yours. Just test with any leaf texture from cgtextures

Comment: @elmo274 zdepth pass doesn't use textures, only geometry. How did you obtain your zdepth image? Is it a mist, depth shader or something else? If you want to get correct zdepth for transparent objects look at this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27044/compositing-fog-destroys-png-alpha-in-images-as-planes-when-using-cycles/27049

Comment: @jerryno its not the texture per say, but the shape of the texture. If the material does not have a leaf texture, the result would be rectangles seen in cegaton's render. But if you add in a texture, the material creates an alpha so the leaf looks like a leaf and not a rectangle. If that makes sense.

Comment: Try increasing the transparency bounces: post:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38111/what-causes-this-mist-pass-glitch

Answer (score -1):

Glossy shaders won't affect the z-pass at all. The z-pass is literally a gray-scale of how far away each pixel is.

The answer to this question is exactly the same as any other question dealing with Cycles noise (though it might not seem like it at first). Noise in regular renders is a precision issue, and the noise here is also a precision issue. The way that Cycles improves precision is with more samples.

It's slightly different with the z-pass in that there's not nearly as many contributing factors to "how far away is this pixel" as there are to "what color is this pixel." But there are some. The main contributor is likely anti-aliasing. But even then, the solution should be the same: render more samples.

cegaton's recommendation to adjust the near and far clipping planes, is also a good idea.

If that doesn't help... well, I may just be mistaken... and that's okay.

Comment: Please read this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36072/is-z-render-pass-accuracy-dependent-on-sample-count-are-others-like-object-id/36089#36089. This answer is wrong.

Comment: Excellent comment. I did not expect that to be the case. I'm interested to experiment with rendering a couple of these with different seeds and stacking them...