# How to render depth pass with alpha channel transparency in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, transparency, render-passes

I have a 3D object in the empty scene. I can click on the "transparent" checkbox to make a render with a transparent background. How can I render depth (or any other) pass with transparent background the same way?

Maybe I can use the alpha channel as a mask in compositor? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27044/compositing-fog-destroys-png-alpha-in-images-as-planes-when-using-cycles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the alpha channel as a mask since transparency is not taken into consideration in the depth pass.

This is how I have done it:

I used the node called "Set alpha".
I Plugged the depth into te "image" and the alpha pass into the "Factor"
the normalize is optional but helps to see the depth better.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how can I do it, what should the node tree look like?

Comment: Just like it's there, that's all there is to it

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!